# How do I mount a harddrive with an option (-o)?

Tags: boot, mount

**Problem**

I want to mount my harddrive with *usrquota* enabled. When mounting, I use the following command:

```
$ mount -t ext4 -o defaults,usrquota,grpquota /dev/sdc1 /home
```

When I check the mounted disk, I see that the option hasn't been added to the disk:

```
$ mount 
/dev/sdc1 on /home type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
```

In other words, the options *usrquota,grpquota* is missing. Can someone help me getting this command working?

**> FSTAB works fine**

In FSTAB I can mount this disk without any issues. I use the following command to mount this harddrive.

```
UUID= /home ext4 defaults,usrquota,grpquota 0 0
```

**> Reason why I mount using a crobjob instead**

Imagine I detach this volume from my server and reboot this server. The server will end up in a emergency state that I cannot control externally (I'm using Azure, by the way). To prevent this from happening, I use the following cron instead:

```
@reboot root sleep 60; mount -t ext4 -o defaults,usrquota,grpquota /dev/sdc1 /home
```

Now you see why I need that option to be working with the mount command. Without this option, I cannot examine the saved data in this drive using *repquota*.

Comment: “Imagine I detach this volume from my server and reboot this server. The server will end up in a emergency state that I cannot control externally” Have you actually experienced this? I got a server booted with swapped `/home` and `/var` mounts and was able to edit `/etc/fstab` and reboot using SSH.

Comment: If the underlying issue is that your home directory is on a volume that may be unavailable at boot time, you might want to consider using [autofs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Autofs)

Comment: @Melebius yes I had, several times actually. When in emergency mode, you cannot access your server with sshd any longer. I haven't found a way to reach these servers since then. Instead I I reverted to an older snapshot, sometimes with (a little) dataloss.

Comment: @steeldriver ok, I'll have a check on autofs! :)